# Two letter or Three Letter Domains?

Tags: dns

why is it ma.tt was able to get a two letter domain, but when i try to get za.ch it says this error (http://screencast.com/t/mbesajy3RA)?

Answer (score 4):

Different domain registrars, and different TLDs (top-level domains, the `.ch` part in this case, representing Switzerland) are free to place whatever restrictions they like for valid domains under their control.

Among other things, the [domain rules](https://www.nic.ch/reg/wcmPage.action;jsessionid=3135C25E0859F3AB0D06722B47A04812?res=EF6GW2JBPVTG67DLNIQXU234MN6SC33JNQQGI7L6) for `.ch` state:

> **3.1.2 Grounds for refusal**
>
> SWITCH will refuse registration of a
>   domain name if:
>
> c. the domain name or the ACE string contains fewer than 3 or more than 63 characters, subject to statutory exceptions or exceptions approved by OFCOM or the Office of Communications;

They also seem to require a correspondence address actually within Switzerland.

Comment: Just off my head (disclosure: I am Swiss): No they don't require a Swiss correspondence address.